No output in LTspice
I have implemented a simple circuit in LTspice which is as follows:

Now, when I want to view the output in the collector, it displays only one line.

Now let's check it in DC mode:

which is exactly correct with manual analysis, but when I connect it to the capacitors, this problem occurs, if I make the capacitors large.
Profile of my resource

By changing the value of the capacitor, the output will be as follows:

One strange thing, when I run it in ac mode, the gain is displayed correctly...

So why is it not like this in transit mode?
How can I get the maximum swing?
Can you guide me on how to solve this problem?
LTspice file

When you cut a wire node numbers may change.

What's the DC bias level at Q1 base?

@winny I edited the third photo and named all three transistor pins.

@Sajadi When posting LTspice schematic screenshots please turn off the grid first to make them easier to read. You should be able to toggle this with Ctrl+G. Toggle it off, take your screenshot, toggle it back on.

@GodJihyo Yes, I will definitely correct all the photos now

@GodJihyo Done!

A transient run is being done (Voltage versus time).
In the set-up box where transient time span, start time, you have Start external supply voltage at 0V checked.
Since the RC time constant at transistor base 360k times 10mf is so very long, a great deal of time is required before it settles to steady state. It does eventually, but not within the 100ms run you have specified.

Here's the original long-time-constant circuit with large 10mf capacitors, done with a transient run with startup parameter deleted:


Honestly, 10,000 seconds will be too long and it will take a long time, so I put the capacitor at 10 microfarads and put a photo of it in the post, but there is still a problem, can you help me?

If you un-check that start external DC supply voltage at 0V, then your transient run will calculate the steady-state bias point where all capacitors are charged to their steady-state values, as they would in AC analysis. Then the transient run will proceed from there, and your transistor collector would be at 1.47V DC....even with those extremely large capacitors.  Your transient directive should be .tran 0 10 0 .5 with "startup" deleted.
